# Segmentation fault due to invalid writes

Tags: c++, class, debugging, segmentation-fault, valgrind

I am trying to create a maze class that can read an input stream that has the description of the maze and return a maze. However when I run a test with this given input stream:

```
20 10
####################
#................<.#
#..................#
#...###............#
#.....#............#
#.....#............#
#...###............#
#..................#
#..................#
####################
```

It gives a segmentation fault, and I run the object file on valgrind to check what is happening:

```
Invalid write of size 8
==2482545==    at 0x4032CD: Maze::setTile(Position const&, Tile*) (maze.cpp:47)
==2482545==    by 0x40347B: Maze::read(std::istream&) (maze.cpp:67)
.....
==2482545==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

I don't really understand why there is an segmentation fault or an invalid write, in my code, I should have allocated the space for each tile inside my setTile function, so there should be space for me to write. I also stacked the tile_collection with my constructor so tile_collection should be initialized when I called Maze(20,10), and the resizing inside setTile should be working. Can you please point out what am I missing? Thank you in advance.

```
Maze::Maze(int width,int height):
  Width(width),Height(height){
  vector<Tile*>* tile_collection=new vector<Tile*>;
}


void Maze::setTile(const Position &pos,Tile *tile){
  tile_collection.resize(pos.getX()+pos.getY()*Width);
  tile_collection[pos.getX()+pos.getY()*(Width)]=tile;
}


Maze *Maze::read(std::istream &in){
  int x;int y;char c;
  if ((in>>x)&&(in>>y)){
      Maze *new_maze=new Maze(x,y);
      //loop over the specified maze dimension
        for (int i=0;i<y;i++){
          for (int j=0;j<x;j++){
            if (in>>c){
              //using tilefactory to change character into a tile
              TileFactory *fac=fac->getInstance();
              Tile* temp=fac->createFromChar(c);
              //if createFromChar fails, return nullptr, otherwise set tile at position j,i
              if (temp==nullptr){
                return nullptr;
              }
              else{
                new_maze->setTile(Position(j,i),temp);
              }
            }
          }
        }
        return new_maze;
  }
  else{
    return nullptr;
  }
}
```

Comment: `vector<Tile*>* tile_collection=new vector<Tile*>;` is assigning to a local variable, not a member variable. You could `tile_collection=new vector<Tile*>;` to assign to the member, but the best thing to do is eliminate the pointer and define `vector<Tile*> tile_collection` as a member variable. Save pointers and dynamic allocation for when you really need them, and that's almost never with a library container like `std::vector` Their job is to handle memory management for you.

Comment: Looking deeper, the use of `.` notation in `tile_collection.resize(pos.getX()+pos.getY()*Width);` suggests the member `tile_collection` is NOT a pointer, so the problem is different from what I described above. What's above is still wrong, it's a memory leak, but probably not related to the bug you're hunting.

Comment: Thank you for your help! umm, so I only have to define vector<Tile*> tile_collection in my header file and don't have to initialize it? And all that resizing inside my getTile will still work?

Comment: `vector` looks after itself. If you have enough information to size it in the constructor, and with the `width` and `height` you do, you could `Maze::Maze(int width,int height):
  Width(width),Height(height), tile_collection(width * height)` and save yourself having to `resize` it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vector<Tile*>* tile_collection=new vector<Tile*>;` will initialize new *local* variable and leak the memory. It is completely unrelated to the member `tile_collection`. If `tile_collection` is a member variable of type `vector<Tile*>` (i.e. *not* a pointer) it will be initialized by the constructor without any explicit code.

Secondly

```
tile_collection.resize(pos.getX()+pos.getY()*Width);
tile_collection[pos.getX()+pos.getY()*(Width)]=tile;
```

causes an out of bounds access. For a vector of size `n` the valid indices are `0...n-1`. 
There also seems to be a logical error. You resize the vector *every time* you write something to it (you also decrease it's size, for example when `pos` is close to `(0, 0)`). Maybe you want something more like this:

Unless the maze can't grow dynamically you only need to resize the vector once, or initialize if with the correct size:

```
Maze::Maze(int width, int height):
  Width(width),
  Height(height),
  tile_collection(width * height) { }
```

and simplify the `setTile` a bit:

```
void Maze::setTile(const Position &pos,Tile *tile){
    tile_collection[pos.getX() + pos.getY() * Width] = tile;
}
```

Comment: thank you! So I will just resize the vector and then use the back method to add elements in my setTile function

Comment: If you want to use `push_back` you need to `reserve()`, not `resize()`. I edited it a bit, maybe this is more what you want.

Comment: You've cleaned up the bug with the constant calls to `resize`, but it's probably better to initialize the `vector` with the correct size in the constructor and remove the `resize` completely. Multiple resizes is probably worse than potentially wasting a few unused pointers-worth of memory.

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, this would be better, assuming the Maze can't grow dynamically.

Comment: You could resize in height, but resizing width will take a lot more work.

Comment: um yeah I think because I know the dimension of the maze from istream, I will just initialize the maze_collection with the inputs. Thank you.

Comment: @M.Chen one last caveat: members are initialized in the order they are defined in the class. Churil's stepped around the problem by using the parameters, but if you `Maze::Maze(int width, int height):
  Width(width),
  Height(height),
  tile_collection(Width * Height) { }` and `tile_collection` is defined before `Width` or `Height` `tile_collection` will be initialized with `Width` and `Height` BEFORE `Width` and `Height` are initialized. Some compilers will warn you. The others... Well, happy debugging.

Answer (score 1):

```
tile_collection.resize(pos.getX()+pos.getY()*Width);
tile_collection[pos.getX()+pos.getY()*(Width)]=tile;
```

is the same as

```
int p = pos.getX()+pos.getY()*Width;

tile_collection.resize(p);
tile_collection[p]=tile;
```

Except, it is now clear you are accessing out-of-bounds. If you want to write to position `p`, you need to allocate at least `p + 1` elements, because in C++ pretty much everything is 0-based.